# somar os valores dos nomes repetidos no DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, winforms, visual-studio

Olá, pessoal tudo bem, tenho uma aplicação onde eu vou adicionando os itens no DataGridView, porem quero somar os valores dos volume, das linhas que estão com o nome iguais, quero criar uma variável para receber o nome repetido e a soma dos valores, tenho o exemplo de código e vou mostra pra vcs poderem me ajudar pq não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: evite colocar imagens, coloque o código na pergunta, é muito mais legível

Comment: perfeito amigo, vou fazer isso obrigado.

Comment: de onde vem os dados do dgv ? onde tem EF no código ?

Comment: os dados estao vindo dos textbox e sendo add ao datagrig.

Comment: private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                CamposGrid();
                dtCargas.Rows.Add  lblCodigo.Text,  txtNomePopular.Text,   txtPlaqueta.Text  
                txtCoc.Text,    txtPicada.Text,txtSecTora.Text, txtD1Dof.Text,   txtD2Dof.Text,
                txtCompDof.Text,  txtVolumeDof.Text,     txtD1.Text,   txtD2.Text,    txtComp.Text,
                txtVolumeCompra.Text,  txtPatio.Text, txtSomaEspecie.Text, txtCodigo.Text,
                dateTimePicker1.Text);     
            }

Comment: Em meu ponto de vista adicionaria os dados do formulário em uma LISTA, depois passaria a lista para o grid, pois dessa forma ficaria fácil fazer o que você quer. Utilizaria Linq, com SUM e DISTINCT para fazer a soma dos valores desejados onde os nome se repetissem.